# Autocomplete, tab-complete email input using AngularJS and Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, email, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to create some sort of a function for an input that can auto complete and tab-complete when a user enters in a letter. It needs to consistently call the service to get all the emails relevant to whatever the user has typed in, show it to the user (max of maybe 50 emails) and then hit tab to finish the email.

Not really sure how to even begin this... I've got my service working so I can definitely pull information from the backend.

Comment: $scope.$watch is your friend. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ui-select was the library I ended up using. It worked for what I needed.